# jquery datatable datetime column sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [Jquery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) in one of my ASP.NET MVC project. My listing pages contains DateTime columns like CreateOn, LastUpdatedOn etc.

I want to enable sorting on these DateTime columns but the problem is that the DisplayFormat and the data on which I want to sort is different.

Means I want to sort the data by keeping time component of DateTime column but I don't want to display time component.

I used the [Ultimate DateTime Sorting Plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) but I can't figure out option in that plugin.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery datatables uses `data-order` attribute in `td` to order. To order datetime column use this technique that i have used and working fine for me
[convert your date in seconds then put that in `data-order`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxfgy.png)

See the image for more explanation